# PGP/GPG Sign and Encrypt using different key size

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

Is it possible or compatible when encrypting file with gpg/pgp, our client is signing it using 1024 bits key (their private key) and then encrypt it using our public 2048 bits key?

Will this cause any issues?

Thanks,
Eka

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no issues.  The operations are completely separate.  The signature is encrypting a hash of the message, and the encryption of the result operates on the message + hash combination as a single message.  Nothing requires the key lengths to be related.

That said, 1024 bit keys are a bit short in the bits and long in the tooth.  You should encourage them to upgrade to 4096 bit keys at their next opportunity.